# Measuring the execution time of a block of code in Jupyter notebook for only one iteration

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter-lab

I want to measure the execution time of a block of code in the Jupyter notebook for only one iteration, but the `%%timeit` magic command measures the execution time for multiple iterations. For instance when I execute the following block :

```
%%timeit
a=2
b=100
c = [i for i in range(1000) if i%2==0]
```

the Jupyter shows me this message:

```
102 µs ± 3.55 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

My problem is that, if I want to measure the execution time of a big block of code which even one iteration of it takes a couple of hours, it may takes several weeks for Jupyter notebook to run that block several times and gives me the average execution time!

Comment: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html - see the docs for control parameters.  `%%timeit -n1 -r1` should do what you want.  I also see a `%time` magic.  `%%timeit` adjusts the number of loops to fit the problem, fewer loops for longer running tasks.